# Setting the fans via the ipmi tools

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

I have several Dell R620 that are in use.  Recently, the cooling of the fans has come into question.  I've yum-installed the ipmitool.  An

```
# ipmitool sensor
```

shows me the information I want to know.  What I don't see is the command(s) to set/reset/increase the air flow of the fans.

I don't want to power down each machine and go into the iDRAC Thermal Settings.

Does anyone know the command to set the max exhaust temperature and/or the ThermalBase Algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, ipmi is rather limited.
You can try `delloem`, `mc` or `nm` commands, however I didn't see proper options in my version while using Dell PowerEdge 2950.

This question better fits Server Fault, you could try there.